# need a help about formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I am using formtastic for form generation
In my app i have two model say Account and Profile but there is no association between them
because in my profile model i have two cols 'property' and 'value'
i have generated form for Account model which has cols like 'username' and 'password' but i want
to add fields in form like 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'  but i don't want to store them in account model i want to store them in profile model like

```
property       value
first_name     Ryan
last_name      Bates
email          ryan@bates.com
```

because of this i don't create any association between these two table.

how can i implement this? can i use semantic_fields_for profile model if there is no association?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but why on earth are you modelling this way? Formtastic is built on top of and for The Rails Way (and common relational database conventions). I would suggest that if you're going to go this far away from standard Rails modelling for this, Formtastic will only make life harder, not easier.

Comment: Thanks Justin French, for your response. I am doing this silly stuff due to client requirement.

Comment: A client has modelling requirements? A client should have business requirements and goals, not technical ones :)